# Create a button in OpenCV GUI without QT

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015

It seems that I can create some elements of the GUI without compiling OpenCV with QT and some I can't,

For example, `cv::createTrackbar(...)` works right out of the box, without re-compiling OpenCV. But `cv::createButton(...)` requires building OpenCv with QT enabled.

Is it possible to create some kind of a button without re-compiling OpenCV?

I don't have any issues building it the correct way QT, but I would like to ask this question for any beginners who may be confused by this problem.

Thanks
-D

Comment: "Is it possible to create some kind of a button without re-compiling OpenCV?" No. OpenCV buttons require QT.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/Dovyski/cvui

Comment: That's a nice API for hobby projects, but the "controls" dont allow for callbacks that OpenCv has for its controls, therefore, the application must sit in a loop waiting for any of the 'buttons' to be pressed. It's single-threaded operation is not principled for modern applications.

Comment: Please check.. https://github.com/ParkSeungwon/opencv-gui. This is event driven